# Get date format in Play

Tags: scala, date, playframework

I am getting date in following format (i'm using play 2.6.13). How do I convert into valid date format.

**Now     :** localhost/api/v1/myapp/table?dateStartQuery=2020-03-23T**13%3A11**

**Required:** localhost/api/v1/myapp/table?dateStartQuery=2020-03-23T**13:11**

**Code :**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

@ApiParam(value = **"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm"**) maybeDateStartQuery:Option[Timestamp] = None,
```

**Routes:**

```
GET        /api/table      controllers.MainController.getDate(uuid: Option[java.util.UUID] ,lastUpdateDate: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] )
```

Comment: It seems like format is correct, but you getting string in encoded format. Try to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html  to decode URL query parameter value.

Comment: Consider not using `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. If for an SQL database, since JDBC 4.2 use `OffsetDateTime` for SQL datatype `timestamp with timezone` (recommended for timestamps) or `LocalDateTime` for SQL `timestamp` without time zone.

Comment: yes i'm trying to convert the timestamp to String, i use this function  `def toTimestamp(o: Option[String]) = o.flatMap(s => Try(Timestamp.valueOf(s)).toOption)
` but it's allways None `toTimestamp(Some("2020-03-23T13:11")) => res0: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None`